# Viewport scaling is breaking when rotated back to portrait

Tags: css, mobile, responsive-design, media-queries, viewport

I am developing a mobile version of my website but I'm encountering some strange behaviour when rotating my device (iPhone). It looks and works fine when rotated to landscape orientation, but when rotated back to portrait, although the content adjusts, the viewport stays stuck at the landscape size. I have two login input fields that are set to 100% width on the page so that they are able to stretch to fit width on rotation:

```
input {
    clear: both;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 18px 10px;
}
```

These input elements seem to be part of the problem because when I change them to auto, the rotation behaves properly. Does anyone know how I can fix this behaviour, as well as keeping the form fields' fluid width intact?

FYI, The viewport is set as follows to allow for a fixed, scaled design:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
```

I have thoroughly looked on StackOverflow for a solution but none of the solutions in other posts work, whether it be changing the meta viewport attributes, using javascript or changing the media queries in CSS. Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Contain the inputs within a parent div and create a CSS rule of `overflow: hidden;` for the parent div.

See the fiddle I created below (on iPhone of course) and let me know if it works!

http://jsfiddle.net/g54pm/3/